# loop through sql results and delete the single rows

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

Im trying to delete persons from a list through a for loop. My problem is now that im trying to find each id to delete the specific row of my database but i dont know how i can do it with a for loop.

My Code right now:

```html
[HttpPost("delUebertrag/")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<ProzessPersonenzuordnungen>> delRecUebertrag([FromBody] recUebertragModel user)
        {
            ProzessPersonenzuordnungen ppz = new();
            for (var i = 0; i <= user.personList.Length; i++)
            {
                Guid personId = new Guid(user.personList[i]);
                ppz.ProzessId = new Guid(user.prozessId);
                var prozessPersonenzuordnungen = _context.ProzessPersonenzuordnungens.Where(p => p.ProzessId == ppz.ProzessId && p.PersonId == personId);

                if (prozessPersonenzuordnungen == null)
                {
                    return NotFound();
                }
                //Everythings works fine above, prozessPersonenzuordnungen haves for Example 2 results
                for(var j = 0; j < prozessPersonenzuordnungen.Count(); j++) // i dont know if Counts is fine, looking for something like length of the results
                {
                    var toDeletingRow = await _context.ProzessPersonenzuordnungens.FindAsync(prozessPersonenzuordnungen.Select(p => p.ProzessPersonenzuordnungId)); // Here i need to go through every singleId of my results, something like p.ProzessPersonenzuordnungId[j](does not work) 
                    _context.ProzessPersonenzuordnungens.Remove(toDeletingRow);
                    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                }
               
            }
            return Ok();
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

The FindAsync can be only used for single item. Instead do

```
var rowsToDelete = _context.ProzessPersonenzuordnungens.Where(x=> prozessPersonenzuordnungen.Select(p => p.ProzessPersonenzuordnungId).Contains(x.Id));
```

And instead of Remove, use

```
_context.ProzessPersonenzuordnungens.RemoveRange(rowsToDelete);
```

And one important thing, **accessing database in a loop is a very bad practice**.
Try to do it without the loop.

**Edit:**

Try this

```
ProzessPersonenzuordnungen ppz = new ProzessPersonenzuordnungen();
        for (var i = 0; i <= user.personList.Length; i++)
        {
            Guid personId = new Guid(user.personList[i]);
            ppz.ProzessId = new Guid(user.prozessId);
            var prozessPersonenzuordnungen = _context.ProzessPersonenzuordnungens.Where(p => p.ProzessId == ppz.ProzessId && p.PersonId == personId)
                .Select((x)=> x.ProzessPersonenzuordnungId);

            if (prozessPersonenzuordnungen == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            var rowsToDelete = _context.ProzessPersonenzuordnungens.Where(x => prozessPersonenzuordnungen.Contains(x.Id));
            _context.ProzessPersonenzuordnungens.RemoveRange(rowsToDelete);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return Ok();
        }
```

Comment: Includes does not work in this Case. "Guid does not Containt a definition for Includes".

Comment: @DeChopper, in place of includes, try contains. It shall work.

Comment: Okay i deleted now the for loop. x.Id does not exist so i changed it to x.ProzessPersonenzuordnungId still not working.

Comment: @DeChopper, I've edited the answer to include the whole section. Try that one.

Comment: x.Id still does not exist, tried it also with some other ways still not working and throwing error 500

Comment: @DeChopper, replace x.Id with the primary key of ProzessPersonenzuordnungens

Comment: I already did :D Same error

Comment: @DeChopper, can you include the error description here?

Comment: POST http://localhost:5000/api/ProzessPersonenzuordnungen/delUebertrag/ 500 (Internal Server Error)

I tried it in debug mode, he goes through the loop correctly and in the last loop the errors comes here: "await _context.SaveChangesAsync();" Seems like he does not find the Rows to delete and so he cant save the change

Comment: @DeChopper, try adding a try-catch block and look into the exception message. Only 500 error doesn't provide any information.